# How to create a condition which allows only resources created in the same CloudFormation stack to assume IAM role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-sts

I'm creating a CloudFormation stack that has a CodeBuild and an IAM role as a resource. I'd like to know if is there a condition that allows only resources created in the same stack to assume the role.

Currently, my stack is defined this way:

```
  CodeBuildProjectIAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: codebuild.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole

  CodeBuildProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
```

The problem is that any CodeBuild project can assume the role above.

When I try to add a condition specifying that only principals with `aws:cloudformation:stack-name` equal stack name can assume the role:

```
  CodeBuildProjectIAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: codebuild.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                aws:PrincipalTag/aws:cloudformation:stack-name: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
```

, I get this error:

`Condition can contain only one colon. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument)`

Comment: I think this is just a syntax error. Try adding `'`, something like: `'aws:PrincipalTag/aws:cloudformation:stack-name:'`.

Comment: @lexicore I've tried `'aws:PrincipalTag/aws:cloudformation:stack-name:'` (got `Template format error: YAML not well-formed`) and `'aws:PrincipalTag/aws:cloudformation:stack-name':` (got `Condition can contain only one colon`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html) I don't believe what you're trying to do is possible a this time.

Specifically:

> You cannot limit permissions to pass a role based on tags attached to that role using the ResourceTag/key-name condition key